# Failed to decode packet: in running virtual controller using google matter

Tags: google-smart-home

Hi I am following this codelab and trying to build a virtual device and controller. I have followed all steps till step 5.

When I open the virtual controller, I try to change the light state to on and I also try to change the level. But there is no change in state of the device and it remains in the off state. In the terminal I am recieving messages like these.

```
Failed to decode packet: Error: Assertion failed
Raw packet: 27,91,51,53,109,27,91,49,109,73,78,70,27,91,48,109,32,32,91,49,54,55,55,56,52,54,50,54,50,46,48,49,48,49,56,53,93,91,52,53,51,58,52,53,55,93,32,67,72,73,80,58,68,77,71,58,32,65,99,99,101,115,115,67,111,110,116,114,111,108,58,32,105,109,112,108,105,99,105,116,32,97,100,109,105,110,32,40,80,65,83,69,41
Received data which length is 1
[RPC] Send rpc 'chip.rpc.Attributes.Read'.
Starting chip.rpc.Attributes.Read on channel 1
Received data which length is 1
Received data which length is 452
```

I wanted to confirm if this is this expected behavior? If it is not, can it be possible to share ways to resolve it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bringing this up. This is not an expected behavior. The virtual image should work. Can you please open a bug in [Public issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) for further investigation and share the the full log from your virtual device? Can you also provide the following info about your setup: computer(which VM and OS do you have), mobile OS version, Google Home app version, Google Hub(what model and Software version do you have).
I’m going to follow up with the team and update you through the issue tracker.

Comment: Corp.google.com does not look like a public issue tracker.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker